# Dont know how to filter an array

Tags: botframework

lets say i have an array like this from an API:

```
  "robots": [
  {
    "name": "R2D2",
    "id": "19385789238"
    "destination": "California"
  },
  {
    "name": "C3PO",
    "id": "c3c3c3c3c3c3"
    "destination": "Ohio"
  },
  {
    "name": "Robby",
    "id": "242324654"
    "destination": "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    "name": "WALL-E",
    "id": "c3c3c3c3c3c3"
    "destination": "California"
  }
  ]
}
```

and im using this to get an id by its name:
`select(where(robots, r, r.name == 'R2D2'), n, n.id)`

How do i sort on the destination its going to in bot framework using the adaptive expression?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your JSON is bad. You're missing some commas (after `id`). So, assuming you're using:

```json
{  "robots": [
  {
    "name": "R2D2",
    "id": "19385789238",
    "destination": "California"
  },
  {
    "name": "C3PO",
    "id": "c3c3c3c3c3c3",
    "destination": "Ohio"
  },
  {
    "name": "Robby",
    "id": "242324654",
    "destination": "Wisconsin"
  },
  {
    "name": "WALL-E",
    "id": "c3c3c3c3c3c3",
    "destination": "California"
  }
  ]
}
```

It would be something like:
`sortBy(robots, 'destination')`

More info on sortBy [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/adaptive-expressions/adaptive-expressions-prebuilt-functions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#sortby). You can also use the playground [here](https://playgroundclient.azurewebsites.net/).